# Is there a way that how to capture pc screen in android?

Tags: android

I'm wondering how to capture PC screen in android app with phone camera.
(It's assumed that my phone is connected to PC in USB debugging.)

The reason why I ask this question is that I'm learning android.

Plus I thought that It's good when I want to get a picture in PC.

Is there idea or thought?

Any opinion is good!

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73146031/edit) your post to explain why you want to have the PC screen image on Android.

Comment: @Morrison Chang
thx! I'll edit the post!

Comment: Android doesn't know anything about the PC, the phone camera is just a camera and would need to be pointed at the PC screen to capture anything. The PC can control Android via [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). Sadly StackOverflow isn't the best place for 'beginner advice' type questions as answers are opinion based which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for answering the question! I'm doing my best with googling but It's not easy to what I want to find. Hav a nc day, Mr. Chang! XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join to computer with any desk from ur mobile then use any recorder app in mobile. This is the easiest and cheapest way to do.

P.S: there is an app for android and ios devices both on their app markets.